how to work with pipes in c using bash commands?
I need some help to understand pipes in C. The point of the program below, written to support linux, is to take lines from stdin that contain bash commands, and pipe (and execute) them together. Attached is the test file I use, as well as the code. Compiling using c99.
cmdfile
ls -s1
sort -n
tail -n 5

pipeline.c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#define MAX_ARGS 10
#define MAX_LINE 256
#define MAX_COMMANDS 100

int main() {
    int cmdSize;
    int cmdAmount = 0;
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    int flag = 0;
    char* cmdList[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_ARGS + 1];
    int i = 0;


    while (fgets(line, 256, stdin)!=NULL && i<MAX_COMMANDS) {

        cmdSize = 0; //reset cmdSize every iter
        cmdAmount++;//keep track of amount of rows in cmdlist

        line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = 0; //strip \n from back of lines cause fgets adds it
        char* token = strtok(line, " ");//tokenise
        char* cmd[11] = {0};

        while(token) {
            cmd[cmdSize] = strdup(token);//strtok returns pointer, so dup value and add to cmd row.

            cmdSize++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        //add row to 2d array
        memcpy(cmdList[i], cmd, sizeof(cmd));
        i++;
    }
    int pipes[cmdAmount-1][2];
    //pipes
    for (int i = 0; i<cmdAmount; i++) {//iterate thru all rows of cmdList.
        //forks
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            if (i != 0) {
                close(pipes[i][1]);
                dup2(pipes[i][0],0);
                close(pipes[i][0]);
            }
            if (i+1 != cmdAmount) {
                close(pipes[i+1][0]);
                dup2(pipes[i+1][1],1);
                close(pipes[i+1][1]);
            }

            
            execvp(cmdList[i][0], cmdList[i]); //execute on child
            perror("Exec error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            if (i != 0 ) {
                close(pipes[i][0]);
                close(pipes[i][1]);
            }
            wait(NULL); // wait until child is finished
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

my problem is, when running ./pipeline < cmdfile, it only runs ls -s1. How do I fix my piping within the forks to allow it to pipe them all together? Some key details, I am trying to use an array to store all pipes, and the input of the lines works fine into cmdList.
tried as seen above.
EDIT:
tried to convert it from an array to just on the fly defining pipes, and it just freezes the terminal and I have to ^C out. Attached below is the updated attempt
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#define MAX_ARGS 10
#define MAX_LINE 256
#define MAX_COMMANDS 100

int main() {
    int cmdSize;
    int cmdAmount = 0;
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    int flag = 0;
    char* cmdList[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_ARGS + 1];
    int i = 0;


    while (fgets(line, 256, stdin)!=NULL && i<MAX_COMMANDS) {

        cmdSize = 0; //reset cmdSize every iter
        cmdAmount++;//keep track of amount of rows in cmdlist

        line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = 0; //strip \n from back of lines cause fgets adds it
        char* token = strtok(line, " ");//tokenise
        char* cmd[11] = {0};

        while(token) {
            cmd[cmdSize] = strdup(token);//strtok returns pointer, so dup value and add to cmd row.

            cmdSize++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        //add row to 2d array
        memcpy(cmdList[i], cmd, sizeof(cmd));
        i++;
    }
    //int pipes[cmdAmount-1][2];
    //pipes
    int prev_pipe[2];
    pipe(prev_pipe);
    for (int i = 0; i<cmdAmount; i++) {//iterate thru all rows of cmdList.
        //forks
        int new_pipe[2];
        
        if (i+1 != cmdAmount) {

            pipe(new_pipe);
        }
        //pipe(prev_pipe);
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            if (i != 0) {
                close(prev_pipe[1]);
                dup2(prev_pipe[0],0);
                close(prev_pipe[0]);
                printf("working1");
            }
            if (i+1 != cmdAmount) {
                close(new_pipe[0]);
                dup2(new_pipe[1],1);
                close(new_pipe[1]);
                printf("working2");
            }

            
            execvp(cmdList[i][0], cmdList[i]); //execute on child
            perror("Exec error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            return 0;
        }
        else {

            wait(NULL); // wait until child is finished
            if (i != 0 ) {
                close(prev_pipe[0]);
                close(prev_pipe[1]);
            }
            if (i+1 != cmdAmount) {
                write(prev_pipe[1], &new_pipe[0], sizeof(new_pipe[0]));
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


@TomKarzes how would I create a pipe from the array?

@TomKarzes so you are saying, ditch the array, and init prev_pipe and new_pipe? I tried that, but when trying to pipe(prev_pipe);, the terminal freezes. How would I ditch the array and just implement it however to get my desired output?

@TomKarzes cannot fix it on my own, question is updated with what I have tried. Please help me by fixing my attempted solution

Ok, I posted a working version as an answer.  See if it works for you.

I think this should fix the pipe problems:
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#define MAX_ARGS 10
#define MAX_LINE 256
#define MAX_COMMANDS 100

int main() {
    int cmdSize;
    int cmdAmount = 0;
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    int flag = 0;
    char* cmdList[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_ARGS + 1];
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(line, 256, stdin)!=NULL && i<MAX_COMMANDS) {

        cmdSize = 0; //reset cmdSize every iter
        cmdAmount++;//keep track of amount of rows in cmdlist

        line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = 0; //strip \n from back of lines cause fgets adds it
        char* token = strtok(line, " ");//tokenise
        char* cmd[11] = {0};

        while(token) {
            cmd[cmdSize] = strdup(token);//strtok returns pointer, so dup value and add to cmd row.

            cmdSize++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        //add row to 2d array
        memcpy(cmdList[i], cmd, sizeof(cmd));
        i++;
    }

    int prev_pipe_out;
    for (int i = 0; i<cmdAmount; i++) { //iterate thru all rows of cmdList.
        int new_pipe[2];

        if (i+1 != cmdAmount) {
            if (pipe(new_pipe) != 0) {
                perror("pipe failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            if (i != 0) {
                close(0);
                dup2(prev_pipe_out, 0);
                close(prev_pipe_out);
            }

            if (i+1 != cmdAmount) {
                close(1);
                dup2(new_pipe[1], 1);
                close(new_pipe[1]);
            }

            execvp(cmdList[i][0], cmdList[i]); //execute on child
            perror("Exec error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else {
            if (i != 0) {
                close(prev_pipe_out);
            }
            if (i+1 != cmdAmount) {
                close(new_pipe[1]);
                prev_pipe_out = new_pipe[0];
            }
        }
    }

    // wait for children to exit
    for (int i = 0; i<cmdAmount; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

On each iteration (except the last), it creates a new pipe for the output of the current command.  It then forks, and links up the pipes, with special cases for stdin for the first command and stdout for the last command.  After creating all of the child processes, it waits for all of them to complete.  It's important to create all of the processes before waiting for any of them, so that they can run in parallel and not block.
